# Run a class function in background and retrieve its status

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

```
import threading
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

def do_other_stuff():
    print("so much stuff to do")

class ABlob:
    def __init__(self, account_name, account_key, container_name, blob_name, file_path):
        self.account_name = account_name
        self.account_key = account_key
        self.container_name = container_name
        self.blob_name = blob_name
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=self.account_name, account_key=self.account_key)

    def get_blob(self):
        download_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.blob_service.get_blob_to_path,
            args=(self.container_name, self.blob_name, self.file_path))
        download_thread.start()

    def get_blob_name(self):
        print(self.blob_name)


first_blob = ABlob(account_name='account_name',
                   account_key='key',
                   container_name='container', blob_name='something.csv',
                   file_path='path')


first_blob.get_blob()
first_blob.get_blob_name()
do_other_stuff()
```

I have Azure Blobs that need to download and upload(not shown). I do not want to wait for them to complete their process as I have other things that should be done. At some point though, I will need to confirm if they have successfully downloaded or uploaded.

With my current code, I have used the threading library. If an error happens in the upload or download process, the thread handling the transaction will exit with an error. I have no way to inform the main thread of completion and the status of the completion.

What do I need to do to be able to get the status of `get_blob`? Is there a another library that has a less dangerous way of handling this situation? I have referenced the following threads but cannot figure out how to combine their different approaches.

[Catch a thread's exception in the caller thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829329/catch-a-threads-exception-in-the-caller-thread-in-python)

[python multiprocessing pool retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533405/python-multiprocessing-pool-retries)

[How to call a async function contained in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009202/how-to-call-a-async-function-contained-in-a-class)

[background function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168508/background-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to do to be able to get the status of `get_blob`?

You can wrap `get_blob` in a function that will store information about whether it succeeded, and store the return value if any. Instead of `target=self.blob_service.get_blob_to_path`, you can write `target=self._get_blob_background`. The new `_get_blob_background` method can call `self.result = self.blob_service.get_blob_to_path` and use `try` and `except Exception as e` to catch all exceptions and, in case of exception, execute `self.result_exception = e`, so that the main thread can distinguish the result from the exception.

Even better, you can use the `concurrent.futures` library to do all that for you:

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

def get_blob(self):
    return pool.submit(self.blob_service.get_blob_to_path,
                       self.container_name, self.blob_name, self.file_path)
```

Now `get_blob()` will run in the background, like in your code, but here it will return a [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object that you can query to find out whether the job completed, and how it completed.

Comment: I had considered your first approach but thought it may be too sloppy. The `concurrent_futures` library is definitely what I was looking for. Is there a consequence to having one pool object per instances of my class? Or should the pool be at a higher level than a per instance basis.

Comment: @supertommy An executor maintains a pool of threads or processes, spawning and destroying them on-demand. If you create an executor for each instance, you will be responsible for calling `close()` on the executor to ensure that its threads are deleted. Also, a new thread will be spawned on each call, which a thread pool is normally designed to prevent to improve efficiency.